# How to zoom in 2x in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and right now I'm trying to get an image zoomed in 2x on a specific corner. Currently I have this method that needs to be changed. [On the right is the original Image, on the left is the result I need to have, the left corned is the one zoomed in 2x.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjJqw.png) What should I change in order to get the result I want? Thanks in advance!

```
public static BufferedImage zoomImage(BufferedImage image) {
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int width = image.getWidth();

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int pixelRGB = image.getRGB(x, y);

            int newPixelColor = pixelRGB;
            image.setRGB(width, y, newPixelColor);
        }
    }

    return image;

}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not a real question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn every pixel in the top left quarter of the original image into 4 pixels in the new image, until you fill up the the buffer. However, you'll realize that starting at the top left corner means that you'll overwrite the pixels near the middle before they are read. You should instead start in the middle; apply the color to the 2x2 square in the bottom right corner. Then repeat the same process, working your way up and to the left. The last operation will be to make the top left 2x2 square the same color as the top left pixel.